# Apache mod_rewrite rule issue that causes an infinite loop

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

We must redirect from this URL:

https://www.ourdomain.com/event/just-an-event-600922?test=620c3c875ceb1ae584920c04d02bc083

to the same without the query string:

https://www.ourdomain.com/event/just-an-event-600922

We've tried with this combination of RewriteCond and RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^test=([A-Za-z0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^event/just-an-event-600922$ https://www.ourdomain.com/event/just-an-event-600922 [L,R=301]
```

But it apparently causes an infinite loop. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but you're missing the `?` at the end. Actually, the query string is appended automatically when it comes to the redirection, resulting in a loop. By using `?`, you kind of reset the query string.

So, your solution:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^test=[A-Za-z0-9]+$
RewriteRule ^(event/just-an-event-600922)$ /$1? [L,R=301]
```

Note 1: you don't need to match and remember the `test` value by using parenthesis, since you don't use it.

Note 2: you can match the RewriteRule so that you don't need to write it one more time for the redirection target (notice the `?` at the end, which is really the point to your initial question here).

Comment: I've tried and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

You can remove `R=301`, then it will not redirect browser to the new URL, but rather rewrite it internally and call your web application with the new query string.

another option is to simplify it:

```
RewriteRule ^test=([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /event/just-an-event-600922 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work, since the ^ indicates everything after the domain must start with that regex. It's not taking the path segment into account.

Can we capture the query string inside the rule? I thought you must use a ReqriteCond for that.